# "It takes me a week to go there" or "It takes a week for me to go there"

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

If someone asked me: "How long does it take you to go there"; Which sentence would be correct, common and natural?

1- It takes me a week to go there

2- It takes a week for me to go there

Comment: Idiomatically, as a US English speaker, I would say "How long does it take to **get** there?"  To *go* implies "to leave", like "I am going to the restaurant right now" means I am leaving right now, not that I am already on my way to the restaurant.

Comment: What do you think? Which one would you prefer?  And why?  Brits would find stangdon's comment just as appropriate as Americans!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I asked which one is correct between numbered sentences.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, because of that I don't know which one I should prefer.